# Have wordpress search results on the same page

Tags: php, wordpress, search

I am trying to display the results of my custom post search in the page I am currently in.   I am posting back to the same page, here's my form:

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform-conferences" action="<?php the_permalink();?>">
    <input type="text" name="search"  value="Enter keywords ..." onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;"/><br />
    <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="posttypeconference" />
    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

Yet, whenever I submit the search, it comes up with a 404 even although the page url is the same one except with the search query, i.e. `mydomain.com/page_where_my_search_form_is.php?search=searchterm`

Comment: I think that if you omit the action attribute from the form, the submit will go to the same url. I don't know why you are getting a 404 error, the url should work without query params, unless you have an error on the page.

Comment: the url does work without the query attributes just fine, but when the search is submitted and the page is then reloaded with queries, thats when I get the 404.

Comment: Do you have any kind of processing going on if the search param is present? Sometimes when using a framework, the PHP errors are masked by displaying a "not found" or "internal server error" page.

Comment: ahh perhaps so, it is wordpress, so I think wp is probably doing something

Comment: ok seems to be a permalink think, as soon as I turned permalinks back to default, my search page works

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML should be like that

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform-conferences" action="">
    <input type="text" name="search"  value="Enter keywords ..." onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;"/><br />
    <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="posttypeconference" />
    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

Your PHP could be something like that

```
<?php
$args = array( 'post_type' => $_POST['post_type'], 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'post_title' => 'LIKE %'.$_POST['search'].'%' );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    the_title();
    echo '<div class="entry-content">';
    the_content();
    echo '</div>';
endwhile;
?>
```

Where you register your custom post make sure it's similar to:

```
add_action('init', 'usb_init');
function usb_init()
{
    $labels = array(
    'name' => _x('USB', 'post type general name'),
    'singular_name' => _x('USB', 'post type singular name'),
    'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'usb'),
    'add_new_item' => __('Add New USB'),
    'edit_item' => __('Edit USB'),
    'new_item' => __('New USB'),
    'view_item' => __('View USB'),
    'search_items' => __('Search USBs'),
    'not_found' =>  __('No usb found'),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __('No usb found in Trash'),
    'parent_item_colon' => ''
);
  $args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'product','with_front' => FALSE),
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'menu_position' => '5',
    'supports' => array('title','excerpt','editor','thumbnail','page-attributes'),
    'taxonomies' => false
);
register_post_type('usb',$args);
}
```

**'public' => true,
'publicly_queryable' => true,
'query_var' => true,**

If that still doesn't work you can try adding: `flush_rewrite_rules();` after you register your custom post

Comment: Tried that, it goes straight to a 404...I don't know what wordpress is doing in the background, but it doesn't like my page having a query at the end of it, its making it be a 404

Comment: If you can check the error logs and show any errors that might help

Comment: it's the PHP error log, could be file with name error_log or similar

Comment: No it's not the way the custom post has been registered, it shows up fine in the normal search results page.

Comment: what does flush_rewrite_rules() do and where do I put it?  Do I delete it after adding it?

Comment: register_post_type('usb',$args);
flush_rewrite_rules();

And run it once this should celar that cached routes

Comment: nope, thats still not sorted it.  It doesn't like me adding queries to the url, and I assume that I can't do it as a post query because then wordpress won't pick up it's a search request